# How to judge a file type both work in python 2 and python 3

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, python-3.x, isinstance

Because file can't use in python 3.

In python 2, we judge a file type can do this:

```
with open("xxx.txt") as f:
    if isinstance(f, file):
        print("ok!")
```

In python 3, we can do this:

```
import io
with open("xxx.txt") as f:
    if isinstance(f, io.IOBase)
        print("ok!")
```

But the second code can't work in python 2.

So, is there a way to judge a file type both work in python 2 and python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for both with a tuple; use a `NameError` guard to make this work on Python 3:

```
import io

try:
    filetypes = (io.IOBase, file)
except NameError:
    filetypes = io.IOBase

isinstance(f, filetypes)
```

You need to test for both on Python 2 as you can use the `io` library there too.

However, it is better to use duck typing rather that testing for `io.IOBase`; see [Check if object is file-like in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661262/check-if-object-is-file-like-in-python) for motivations. Better to check if the method you need is present:

```
if hasattr(f, 'read'):
```

Note that `io.IOBase` doesn't even include `read`. And in Python 2, `StringIO.StringIO` is a file-like object too, one that `isinstance(.., file)` will not support.