# Jinja2 dump into an object?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I want to be able to dump into an object.

According to the documentation, I can dump into a file or a file like object.

What can I use as a file like object?

*Obs.: I don't want to save it nor display it. Its a downloadable config template for a router thats created on the fly from data stored in the database.*

```
env = Environment(autoescape=False, optimized=False)    

config_file = None
device_config = None
device_config = env.from_string(config_template.config)
device_config.stream(
  STR         = site.location.upper()[:4],
).dump(config_file)
```

Reason being is I want to use a content disposition to output the file to a users browser with django.

EDIT:
tested with stringIO

```
import StringIO
>>> config_file = StringIO
>>> device_config = None
>>> device_config = env.from_string(config_template.config)
>>> device_config.stream(
...   STR         = site.location.upper()[:4],
... ).dump(config_file)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1167, in dump
    fp.write(item)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write'
>>>
```

Thanks

Comment: you wanna render a dynamic report and show it in your django template? why don't you render it to a HTML + CSS file, save it into your server and display it in your django environment?

Comment: i dont want to save it nor display it, its a downloadable config template for a router thats created on the fly from data stored in the database.

Comment: @AlexW : You should use `StringIO.StringIO()` to make a new object.  Right now `config_file` is pointing to the module, not an object of type `StringIO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used jinja2, but I suspect you can use a `StringIO` to get the desired content as a string.

The following ought to work, but I can't (easily) test it...

```
from StringIO import StringIO

env = Environment(autoescape=False, optimized=False)

sio = StringIO()

device_config = env.from_string(config_template.config)
device_config.stream(
  STR         = site.location.upper()[:4],
).dump(sio)

content = sio.getvalue()
```

However, if you just want a string, it looks like you should use the `render()` method instead...

```
env = Environment(autoescape=False, optimized=False)

device_config = env.from_string(config_template.config)
content = device_config.render(
  STR         = site.location.upper()[:4],
)
```

...but, again, I can't easily test it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, file-like objects are just things that act like files in some way (typically by implementing `read` and/or `write`).  I like the answer given to [Check if object is file-like in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1661354/1062499).

So, in your case, it seems it's enough if your `config_file` object is of a type that is not derived from a string type, and that implements the `write` method.  You can verify this with a quick peek at the source of [jinja2.TemplateStream.dump](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/760ce60dccd6bb9d69378a258f7d0ce086b818ac/jinja2/environment.py#L1136).

Comment: not quite sure i understand, what type should i set config_file to?

Comment: You can use any type that implements `write` (or define your own class with a `write` method).  The right choice will depend on what you're trying to do.  For getting started, you might start testing with [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html).