# Base class for open file objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I want to add some custom behavior to a file object, such as returned by `open()`. According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23796737/699305), there is (or was) no single base type for all file-like objects. Is this really still true? How about `io.IOBase`, or one of *its* subclasses, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24812058/699305)? Or perhaps by now there is an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) that I could use?

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085292/subclassing-file-objects-to-extend-open-and-close-operations-in-python-3), but (besides being quite old) the issues there are about customizing the `close()` method (best done with a context manager). So this does not answer my question (and please don't mark this question as a duplicate of it!).

Comment: What "custom behavior" are you trying to add?

Comment: Well, the type returned by `open` depends on how you called it...

Comment: Is there a reason you *need* a base class? Thanks to the magic of duck typing, it shouldn't need to matter (particularly if you just wrap the underlying object and pass through any calls you don't recognize). I can think of several other approaches to building type-agnostic wrappers as well.

Comment: Ideally I want to know a base class from which I can derive a subclass, so I can avoid playing tricks like overriding base classes etc. So it's more about the creation type... duck typing is for the consumer. With this question I'm asking for information about the situation with file objects. Maybe the answer is still "open file objects come in varieties that have nothing in common", maybe it's not.